# Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug] error on configChanges

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

I've made some changes in AndroidManifest.xml file to trigger screen orientation events. here's my AndroidManifest.xml file...

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.domain.product">

    <application
        android:name=".Product"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity 
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|screenLayout" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And this's build.gradle...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.product"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 9
        versionName '2.1'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
```

After `android:configChanges`, gradle is displaying an error in **Messages** and **Event Log** while building the project. See errors in below images...

[image: Messages]
[image: Event Log]

In-spite of these errors, application is running successfully in emulator and devices. But there's something wrong that's why error has been displayed. Do anybody has idea what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your android minimum target sdk API level is lower than **API level 13** which `screenSize` and `orientation` needs.

Read more at [android:configChanges](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config).

Comment: Please review updated question, I've added build.gradle file

Comment: I've test your code. Nothing is wrong. Please delete the `android:configChanges` line and rewrite it again. Maybe there is invisible character in the line.